# In python, 6.0%1.0 , I am getting 0.999999999999 , How to get the answer as 0.0

Tags: python-2.7

When ever I am trying to do the following in python(compiler that comes in built in mac) 6.0%1.0 , I am getting 0.999999999999 .  How to get the answer as 0.0

### Here is the code :-

```
values=30.24
alist=list()
boolean=0
count=0
print 'start'
while(boolean==0):
        print 'before entering',values
        print 'values%1' , (values%1)
        if(values%(1.0)==0.0):
            boolean=1;
        alist.append(int(values))
        count=count+1;
        svalues=(values)-(alist[count-1])
        print svalues,alist[count-1],count
        values=svalues
        if(values==0.0):
            boolean=1;
        else:
            values=1/(values)
print 'end'
```

Comment: What should I do , if I need the answer of moduls to be 0.0

Comment: What are you trying to test for by computing %1.0?

Comment: It's not for testing , I had to solve a problem.
 where number needed to rounded of and then, the remaining decimal part needs to reciprocated and the process goes on.
Example:-
30.24
a=30(rounding)
b=1/0.24

Comment: I ask since I suspect you're testing if a floating point is an integer. There are more computationally stable techniques available for that. But please read the duplicate first.

Comment: It's not for testing , I had to solve a problem.
where number needed to rounded of and then, the remaining decimal part needs to reciprocated and the process goes on.
Example:-
30.24
b=30.24
a=30(rounding)
b=1/0.24
b=4.16666667
a=4(round)
b=1/0.1666667,b=6.0
a=6(round)
Here, even though I am getting a=6.0 but
b-a (6.0-6), I am getting the answer as 0.999